# Map image as texture to plane in a custom shader in THREE.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, shader

I'm trying to load 2 images as textures, interpolate between them in the fragment shader and apply the color to a plane. Unfortunately, I can't even display a single texture.

I'm creating the plane and loading images as follows:

```
const planeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(imageSize * screenRatio, imageSize);

loader.load(
    "textures/IMG_6831.jpeg",
    (image) => {
        texture1 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: image });
        //texture1 = new THREE.Texture({ image: image });
    }
)
```

It displayed the image on the plane correctly when I used MeshBasicMaterial directly as a material for Mesh as normal. When trying to do the same in a custom shader I get only black color:

```
const uniforms = {
    texture1: { type: "sampler2D", value: texture1 },
    texture2: { type: "sampler2D", value: texture2 }
};

const planeMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    uniforms: uniforms,
    fragmentShader: fragmentShader(),
    vertexShader: vertexShader()
});

const plane = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeometry, planeMaterial);
scene.add(plane);
```

Shaders:

```
const vertexShader = () => {
    return `
        varying vec2 vUv; 

        void main() {
            vUv = uv; 

            vec4 modelViewPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
            gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewPosition; 
        }
    `;
}

const fragmentShader = () => {
    return `
        uniform sampler2D texture1; 
        uniform sampler2D texture2; 
        varying vec2 vUv;

        void main() {
            vec4 color1 = texture2D(texture1, vUv);
            vec4 color2 = texture2D(texture2, vUv);
            //vec4 fColor = mix(color1, color2, vUv.y);
            //fColor.a = 1.0;
            gl_FragColor = color1;
        }
    `;
}
```

To fix it, I tried:

- ensured that the plane is visible by shading it with a simple color
- ensured that uv coordinates are passed to shader by visualizing them as color
- ensured that `texture1` and `texture2` are defined before passing them to the shader
- using `THREE.Texture` instead of `THREE.MeshBasicMaterial`
- changing uniform type in js `texture1: { type: "t", value: texture1 },`

I think the problem might be in the part of passing the texture as uniform to the shader. I might be using the wrong type somewhere.. I'd appreciate any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `loader` is a `TextureLoader` then it calls you with a texture so

```
loader.load(
    "textures/IMG_6831.jpeg",
    (texture) => {
        texture1 = texture;
    }
)
```

otherwise while it's not a bug, `type` is not used for three.js uniforms anymore.

```js
const planeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(1, 1);
const loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
let texture1;
loader.load(
    "https://i.imgur.com/KjUybBD.png",
    (texture) => {
        texture1 = texture;
        start();
    }
);

const vertexShader = () => {
    return `
        varying vec2 vUv; 

        void main() {
            vUv = uv; 

            vec4 modelViewPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
            gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewPosition; 
        }
    `;
}

const fragmentShader = () => {
    return `
        uniform sampler2D texture1; 
        uniform sampler2D texture2; 
        varying vec2 vUv;

        void main() {
            vec4 color1 = texture2D(texture1, vUv);
            vec4 color2 = texture2D(texture2, vUv);
            //vec4 fColor = mix(color1, color2, vUv.y);
            //fColor.a = 1.0;
            gl_FragColor = color1;
        }
    `;
}

function start() {
  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
  const scene = new THREE.Scene();
  
  const camera = new THREE.Camera();
  
  const uniforms = {
      texture1: { value: texture1 },
      texture2: { value: texture1 },
  };

  const planeMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
      uniforms: uniforms,
      fragmentShader: fragmentShader(),
      vertexShader: vertexShader()
  });

  const plane = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeometry, planeMaterial);
  scene.add(plane);

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.111.0/build/three.min.js"></script>
```

also `TextureLoader` returns a texture so if you're rendering continously in a requestAnimationFrame loop you can do write it like this

```js
const planeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(1, 1);
const loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
const texture1 = loader.load("https://i.imgur.com/KjUybBD.png");
const texture2 = loader.load("https://i.imgur.com/UKBsvV0.jpg");

const vertexShader = () => {
    return `
        varying vec2 vUv; 

        void main() {
            vUv = uv; 

            vec4 modelViewPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
            gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewPosition; 
        }
    `;
}

const fragmentShader = () => {
    return `
        uniform sampler2D texture1; 
        uniform sampler2D texture2; 
        varying vec2 vUv;

        void main() {
            vec4 color1 = texture2D(texture1, vUv);
            vec4 color2 = texture2D(texture2, vUv);
            gl_FragColor = mix(color1, color2, vUv.y);
        }
    `;
}

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
const scene = new THREE.Scene();

const camera = new THREE.Camera();

const uniforms = {
    texture1: { value: texture1 },
    texture2: { value: texture2 },
};

const planeMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    uniforms: uniforms,
    fragmentShader: fragmentShader(),
    vertexShader: vertexShader()
});

const plane = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeometry, planeMaterial);
scene.add(plane);

function render() {
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.111.0/build/three.min.js"></script>
```

The textures will be blank but three.js will update them when the images have loaded.

You might be interested in some more [up to date tutorials](https://threejsfundamentals.org)

Comment: yep, the problem was in assigning the texture from the loader. I changed:

``texture1 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: image });``

to:

``texture1 = image;``

and it worked. Thanks!